# ¿occupancy grid from a laser network system?

Tags: navigation, simulation, costmap, stage, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm looking for a way to create a map of a environment in which there are statics lasers and mobile robot with lasers. I found occupancy_grid_utils libraries and costmap_2d package and I think this can help in create a occupancy grid from a single laser topic.

I want to know if there is something in ROS that merge the grids retrieved by the previous process. Also, if someone have any suggestion on how to use occupancy_grid_utils or costmap_2d, please let me know.

Gustavo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60438/%C2%BFoccupancy-grid-from-a-laser-network-system?/) by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 756 on 2013-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Merging maps is a pain. The costmap_2d is setup to allow multiple sensors as input to a single occupancy grid.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1